# How to use Reactjs to authenticate user login using oauth2 Password Grant?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

My friends and I are building this feedback web application using Spring-Boot Java for backend and Reactjs for frontend. We recently figured out how Oauth2 works and where able to set it up and test it using Postman.

Now we are stuck on trying to make a POST fetch in Reactjs that includes the ClientID, Secret, Username, Password and returns the Token. We were able to do a regular POST request and save a user on our server but the fact that the authorization post requires  more parameters has complicated things for us.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
export function PostData(type, userData)  { //disregard parameters for now
  let BaseURL = "http://localhost:8080/";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(
      "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=user&password=user123",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          clientId: "my-trusted-client",
          clientSecret: "secret",
          scope: "user_info"
        })
      }
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        resolve(res);
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

All I am doing is a "static" request to our Rest API. I am trying to recreate in Reactjs what I do in Postman:

Is there anyone who can help me rewrite my code above so that I can authenticate the user trying to signin?
Also, any recommendations on how to move forward after receiving the token?

We are students trying to learn more about our CS passion, any advice is deeply appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 requests expect a request with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-encoded, which means you need to send a x-www-form-encoded body, not json (e.g. grant_type=password&username=...)

```
fetch(
  "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token",
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-encoded"
    },
    body: “grant_type=password&clientId=my-trusted-client&username=user&password=user123&scope=user_info“
  }
)
```

Also note that you shouldn’t include the client secret when sending requests from an untrusted client (I.e. anything not running on your servers). It isn’t necessary and could expose the secret to attackers.